# ListView inside a Spinner : adapter conflict for event detection

Tags: android, events, listview, spinner

I have a [listview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) embed in a [spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) within the onCreate method. I want to fire a  [toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) msg on the list items on click event but can't set up the onClick listener on the ListView items. I'm not  using any custom adapters. I guess the same type of simple adapter is used for both the spinner and the listview therefore it generates some compiling frustrations.

I keep focused on the error obtained for `"lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`" :

> The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the
>   inherited abstract method
>   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int,
>   long)

How to manage to setup that click event on the listview items keeping using simple adapters ?
Shall I somehow "rename" the listview adapter or how to proceed then .. ?

Pseudo code

```
// ...
import android.widget.AdapterView;
/* manually added */
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

// ... some code
        // Set Spinner listener
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View v, int position, long id) {

// ... some code


                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()) {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some msg" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

}

}
```

Comment: "I have a listview embed in a spinner within the onCreate method" -- I will be stunned if that works.

Comment: well it does work like a charm apparently, using a List of hash for the listview data and requirying myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but I'm strugglying to fire Toast on the listview items.

Comment: Spinner it self depends on an adapter, and the popup it shows is not much different from a `ListView`. So why are you embedding a list view inside a spinner popup ? You need multiple adapters, not multiple `ListViews`. Also, setup the click event handlers inside the adapter's `getView()` method if you want to capture individual events of Views in spinner popup.

Comment: Because based on the spinner user returned choice, the grid listview shows different data. I don't need to grab any other events in the spinner popup.

Comment: If you are really embedding ListViews inside Spinners (that is, you have a ListView as a child of a Spinner in your view hierarchy) you 1) misunderstand the purpose of both ListView and Spinner and 2) are in for a world of very strange bugs even if you think it's working now. I hope that what you really mean is that you have a Spinner in one part of your UI that controls the content of a ListView in another part of your UI, not that one is a child view of the other.

Comment: That's right, I have a spinner controlling the contents of a ListView, as described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a spinner and a list view in the same activity. Based on the spinner selection, I update a listview. I also update the same listview from other events like button events for example. The code principle is as described in the question.

I confirm this way works perfectly and I solved my problem that had ntg to do with the spinner/ListView interactions but with the way I fetched data to feed the list.

To illustrate a bit the result, my layout looks similiar to [this](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/) but with buttons additional  to the spinner, both of them driving the listview result.